# Norm of image in linear transformation

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

If the Eigen values of a linear transformation from $R^2 $ to $R^2$, are $a,\, b$, which are non zero, 
$a\,<\,b$, can there be a non zero input vector, Norm of whose image is greater than $b$ times the norm of input vector?
can there be a non zero input vector, Norm of whose image is less than $a$ times the norm of input vector?
 I think it can. Since Eigen values are for the vectors which do not change direction.

Comment: Eigen values a,b are non zero.

Comment: This should cover both cases: $\begin{bmatrix}1/2 & 0 \\ -1&1\end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: So it's possible for any non zero values of a,b , right? The answer given in the book said not possible, so I was just confirming.

Comment: The statement is wrong without additional assumptions.

Comment: U mean the statement in the book?

Comment: It's possible for separate cases. For greater than b, and less than a separately

Comment: yes the statement in your book seems to be wrong or you have omitted some assumptions.

Comment: Obviously, one input can't satisfy both conditions at the same time, as they exclude each other.

Comment: The values of a,b given in book are 2/3, 9/5.

Comment: the eigenvalues alone don't tell anything. Is the matrix supposed to be positive definite? Then, it is true.

Comment: No constraint on the matrix.

Comment: then it is wrong. Try make a own counter example (hint: triangular matrix)